CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when running python-script with shazamio on Mac?
i try to run the following code on a Mac-Computer:
import asyncio
from shazamio import Shazam
import os, sys
import pprint

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
fn = os.path.join(path, "Tinashe Ft. Tyga - Nasty XXX - (A.D. Twerk Edit Dirty-).mp3")

async def main():
  shazam = Shazam()
  out = await shazam.recognize(fn)  # rust version, use this!
  pprint.pprint(out)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

on one computer it works fine without any problems but on the other Mac-Computer i get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aiohttp/connector.py", line 1098, in _wrap_create_connection
  File "asyncio/base_events.py", line 1081, in create_connection
  File "asyncio/base_events.py", line 1111, in _create_connection_transport
  File "asyncio/sslproto.py", line 528, in data_received
  File "asyncio/sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
  File "ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkMusic.py", line 101, in <module>
  File "asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
  File "checkMusic.py", line 28, in main
  File "shazamio/api.py", line 584, in recognize
  File "shazamio/api.py", line 597, in send_recognize_request_v2
  File "shazamio/client.py", line 57, in request
  File "aiohttp_retry/client.py", line 158, in __aenter__
  File "aiohttp_retry/client.py", line 119, in _do_request
  File "aiohttp/client.py", line 663, in _request
  File "aiohttp/connector.py", line 563, in connect
  File "aiohttp/connector.py", line 1032, in _create_connection
  File "aiohttp/connector.py", line 1366, in _create_direct_connection
  File "aiohttp/connector.py", line 1335, in _create_direct_connection
  File "aiohttp/connector.py", line 1100, in _wrap_create_connection
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host amp.shazam.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)')]
[PYI-1342:ERROR] Failed to execute script 'checkMusic' due to unhandled exception!
logout

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.

Is there any workaround regarding this CERT-Error so i can get the script running on any Mac-computer?
